# Paragraph of text validation using cypress

Tags: cypress

I am new to cypress.
Would like to know what is the best approach to test a paragraph of text?

Should I just copy paste them into single line and assert them?

Or any other better way i can keep them into another file, read as parameter in step?

```
Example:
1)  Question 1:
 A) is these preferences? *
•   food and drinks
•   outdoor activities such as cycling, jogging, hiking.
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depends the way that you'll get it. If you get all the paragraph at once, you may use `cy.get('#allMyParagraph').should('include', textToCheck)`

If you get it setp by step, you can check by step too.

`cy.get('#firstParagraphStep).should('eq', fisrtPart) cy.get('#secondParagraphStep).should('eq', secondPart) ...`

Comment: so "textToCheck" i replaced with whole chunk of this ? 1)  Question 1:
 A) is these preferences? *
•   food and drinks
•   outdoor activities such as cycling, jogging, hiking.

Comment: What should be the value inside #allMyParagraph?

Comment: It's a hypothetical code, will depend on how you'll map the paragraph a whole or step by step.

The "textToCheck" is all paragraph text  to be validated